# What to do when the Block element in a BEM component doesn't need any styles?

Tags: css, bem

Let's say I have a structure like this:

```
<article class="product">
  <header class="product__header">
    <h1 class="product__headline">Headline</h1>
    <img class="product__hero" src="" alt="">
  </header>

  <p class="product__description">Content</p>
</article>
```

As the Block element `article` brings all the styles it needs by default, it actually doesn't have any CSS. So I'm not defining it in the CSS like this, because it only clutters the styles:

```
.product { }
```

But I'm unsure about the HTML. Should it be

```
<article class="product"></article>
```

… anyways or simply …

```
<article></article>
```

… as there are no styles attached?

*What is the right thing to do when usin BEM?*

Comment: i think you have to add the class attribute anyway, however you can use a javascript that gives an empty class attribute to every element that doesn't have it

Answer (score 6):

As I understand it, the idea with BEM is to use a standard and have a markup ready for any present or future CSS, so you would **always include the class**, even if you don't use it right now.

Another good reason is that the parent class improves readability and order for anyone looking at the markup. I would even suggest you to include the class in your CSS and left it blank, functioning almost like a subtitle, with the potential to be useful later on.

Finally, BEM recommends against nesting elements in the stylesheet, which means preferring the use of classes even in the smallest children (like a `strong` tag inside a `p`). Seems natural, then, to have a class in the parent as well.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure about leaving the empty class definitions in the CSS. I have them but as comments. Otherwise the parser would raise a warning, that there's something cluttering the source. But I guess I'll keep the classes in the HTML to make the structure visible for now.

Comment: Regarding your last point and readability, while BEM does recommend against nested selectors, sometimes it's more readable to use nested selectors in order to exclude repetitive class names (overkill) in the markup for simple cases like when you target <li>s within <ul> or <p>s within <div>.
[Nesting is appropriate if you need to change the styles of elements **relative to the state of the block** or the theme set.](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#nested-selectors) Though, I don't agree with BEM's example of nesting a class selector within a class selector as this voids my above point.

Answer (score 4):

Keep the class to keep your independence. Future changes might require you style . This approach has several advantages:

1. *In 2 months* you'll still be able to determine the module components and structure without further ado
2. You *and everybody else* will know that  is the component container even if you add further wrapping elements in-between.
3. You might be able to alter the layout without touching the HTML
4. No dependency between HTML semantics and layout.
5. All present structure is mirrored into the layout so you can see all variants and elements in the CSS. Get things out of your head

Finally, I agree with you that CSS clutter isn't nice but it could be useful, especially when you're working on a larger codebase with a larger team where you need to rely on standards.
On your parser/IDE: it will probably be configurable to ignore such entries. Your build process should be able to remove these empty selectors so it doesn't make its way into production CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a similar scenario, If you are following BEM, then keep that class in the article element, since it will help in maintenance(such as removing unused styles, better understand markup).

for example(in product.scss):-

```
.product {
    &__header {
      font-size: 1.7rem
      // etc...
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding....

Note:- Depends upon your markup, you can hoist block element class responsibility to the parent element and updated child class with new parent class.(eg:- .root__prdHeader)